# scala Compilation Error Implicit session

Tags: scala

```
Compilation error
not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class index.
Unspecified value parameter session.
In /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/controllers/Application.scala:69
    if (request.session.isEmpty == false) {
      println("check_point 2")
      //session.get("user").map { user ⇒ Ok(user) }
      Ok(views.html.index())
    } else {
      Ok("Error")
    }
  }





#index.scala.html

 @(implicit session: Session)
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  more html code...........
```

How can i get  session value

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method write this as first line

```
implicit val session = request.session
```

Comment: Thanks tho, I figured it out , this is working @()(implicit session: Session)